# How can I resize the system partition in NAND using PhoenixSuit / Livesuit?

Tags: rom-flashing

I'm using a Android 4.2.2 ROM (sun7i_android_sugar-cubieboard2-8192cu.img) for Cubieboard.

I need more room in system partition for install more goodies!

After flashing, the partition table is like this:

```
NAME          SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
nand          3.8G
|-nand1        16M            Volumn
|-nand2        16M
|-nand3        16M
|-nand4       512M
|-nand5       512M
|-nand6        16M
|-nand7        32M
|-nand8       320M
|-nand9        16M            PRIVATE
|-nand10      256M
`-nand11      2.1G
```

The SYSTEM partition is the nand4 (nandd). As you can see, its size is 512MB.
(http://linux-sunxi.org/Android/partitions)

Inspecting the sys_partition.fex file, I can see nandd info:

```
;------------------------------>mmcblk0p7/nandd
[partition]
    name         = system
    size         = 1048576
    downloadfile = "system.fex"
    user_type    = 0x2
```

The first point is: 1048576 is not 512MB ( it's 1GB ).

Any changes in this file do NOT changes anything in final result after flashing the re-packed image (the partitions size does not change).

How can I change the partitions size in "Stock" ROMs before flashing to NAND?

1. All of these steps is working fine: Unpacking stock ROM, repacking stock ROM, flashing stock ROM (with PhoenixSuit).
2. I don't need resize the partition IN the device. I need resize BEFORE flashing, to share my new ROM with other people.

Comment: The size is probably in 512-byte sectors, and 1048576 sectors is 512 MiB. And everything related to the internal partition table is usually highly specific to the device (or, at best, to a series of similar devices based on the same reference platform).

Comment: @Sergey Vlasov : I think PhoenixSuit creates the partition table during flashing process, using the sys_partition.fex file ...

Comment: The full history is here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=46563720#post46563720

Comment: @Sergey Vlasov you're write but don't solves the problem.

Comment: same problem here with a different board (Marsboard A20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will consider not possible to tell PhoenixSuit resize Android partitions.
So I will give up.

Comment: Seems the XDA people found a way to do this. Follow this post : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1753473&page=19

Answer (score 1):

You must say yes when PhoenixSuite ask if you want to format the flash, Else it don't change the partition size, even if you changed the sys_partition.fex.